# How do I prevent a UL from taking on the full height properties of a drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a sticky navigation bar that is nearly complete in terms of look and feel. However, anytime that I add a drop down menu within any of the links it creates an invisible field that will hide text that gets within it. After some digging, I discovered that the UL takes on the full height properties of the drop down, even if it is currently invisible. My goal is to make the drop down menu its own entity if possible, so that this doesn't occur. The final result would make the menu just have a higher z index and only cover up what's directly beneath it until you moved the mouse away from it.

While I'm on this, I'm also having a small problem with the drop down menu appearing while hovering over the space where the elements would appear. This is an undesired effect, and I believe is the source of the problem.

Here is what happens with the drop down menu present:

[image: With Drop Down Menu]

Here is what happens without it:

[image]

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shadowfang/pn21cncj/). If you are having issues with the logo appearing, just look at the website. Also keep in mind I have not optimized for smaller screens as of yet, so expand the width until the navigation bar is horizontal.

A link to the website: http://www.wolvesofthedust.com/

My Current Code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>The Den</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" href="style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" />
  <script type ="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script type ="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="status"></div>
    <div class="logo">          
        <center><a href="http://www.wolvesofthedust.com/"><img src="Images/WolvesoftheDustSiteHeader.png" height="auto" width="100%" border="0" alt=" photo WolvesoftheDustSiteHeader.png"/></a></center>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class ="navigation">   
        <nav>
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><a href="#">|||</a>
                    <ul class="Dropdown">
                        <a href="#">Shadows and Chaos</a>
                        <a href="#">Fate of Feravis</a>
                        <a href="#">Magnetix</a>
                        <a href="#">Tools</a>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class ="Logo2">
    <img src="Images/WolvesoftheDustSmallLogo.png" alt="WolvesoftheDustSmallLogo" width="100%" height="70px"</a>
    </div>
    <div class="EmptySpace">
    </div>
    <div class ="content">
        <center><h2>THIS WEBSITE IS UNDER CONSTRUCTION!!! TAKE NOTHING HERE YOU SEE SERIOUSLY FOR THE TIME BEING!!!</h2></center> <!-- This is where I will likely have the table located with nicely written dialogue... but if the table isn't needed above then I may as well continue this practice elsewhere. Did I learn all about tables and arranging code properly for nothing? -->
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <p><!-- Interestingly enough it took me a while to realize that P stood for paragraph... considering people normally only wrote a single sentance per line with a "p" tag. Stupid examples and my insinuations based on them -->The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000;
}

body {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 93%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 40px 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #7d0000;
}

a,
a:link,
a:visited {
    color: blue;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {margin-top: 0;}

p {margin: 0 0 1em 0;}

.logo {
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 2px solid #7d0000;
}

.navigation {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.logo2 {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.content {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

h1 {
    background-color: #305782;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 60px 25px;
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    z-index: 500;
    background-color: #000; 
}

.nav-placeholder {
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 65px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}

.fixed .nav-inner {
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.fixed .nav-inner-most {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #000;
}

nav ul {
display: table;
text-align:center;
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
margin: 15px;
text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a:link,
nav ul li a:visited {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #7d0000;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid #7d0000;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #28bfa1;
    color: #FFF
}

nav ul li:hover .Dropdown {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}

.Dropdown {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

/*.Dropdown li {
    display: block;
}*/

.Dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

.Dropdown li a:hover, .Dropdown .current-item a {
    background: #3e3436;
}


.Logo2 {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 300;
}


.EmptySpace {
    height: 250px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    nav ul li{
        display: inline;
   }
}

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // define variables
    var navOffset, scrollPos = 0;

    // add utility wrapper elements for positioning
    jQuery("nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
    jQuery("nav").wrapInner('<div class="nav-inner"></div>');
    jQuery(".nav-inner").wrapInner('<div class="nav-inner-most"></div>');

    // function to run on page load and window resize
    function stickyUtility() {

        // only update navOffset if it is not currently using fixed position
        if (!jQuery("nav").hasClass("fixed")) {
            navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;
        }

        // apply matching height to nav wrapper div to avoid awkward content jumps
        jQuery(".nav-placeholder").height(jQuery("nav").outerHeight());

    } // end stickyUtility function

    // run on page load
    stickyUtility();

    // run on window resize
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        stickyUtility();
    });

    // run on scroll event
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

        scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
            jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");
        } else {
            jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
        }

    });

});

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 600) {
    $('.Logo2').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.Logo2').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Thank you in advance,

Shadowfang

Comment: Yes! Like that. As far as resizing the width of the menu to make it look better, I'm guessing I'd just adjust the parent?

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer to explain what I changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `.Dropdown` element has the style of `position: relative;` and `opacity: 0;` which means it is hidden, but is still taking up room in the DOM.

To create these kinds of dropdown nav menus people usually use absolute positioning to solve this. When you position something absolute it no longer takes up room in the DOM, but it has to be anchored to a parent element with `position: relative;`. In this case that would be the `nav > ul > li`.

So to fix this you will need to update these styles:

```
nav  ul  li {
  position: relative; /* add this for an anchor point*/
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Dropdown {
    position: absolute; /* add this to position the dropdown off the li parent */
    top: 100%; /* put it at the very bottom of the li*/
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pzfLyxn8/2/) for a demo.

Also you had this responsive style in the fiddle:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    nav ul li{
        display: inline;
   }
}
```

You should change that to

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    nav ul li{
        display: block;
   }
}
```

But you said you *I have not optimized for smaller screens as of yet* so I assumed this style was just for the demo.

Comment: Thank you! That explains everything very nicely. Also thanks for fixing the media screen part too :) How would I adjust the parent width to make the rest fall into place correctly? I've tried throwing width attributes into the HTML portion of that one link with no luck.

Comment: Ignore my last question, I decided to leave the width the same on the parent object, and adjust the size of the drop down menu to make it look better.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you use opacity: 0; or visibility: hidden; you always reserve the space despite of hiding element. http://joxi.ru/YmEagVJs0GkBpm On the other hand you may add position: absolute; if you need opacity: 0;